# Write output of command to a log file

Tags: shell, ksh

I have functions in an "environment" file to output date and command outputs of my scripts like these:

```
LogWrite ()
{
    print `date "+%Y%m%d %H%M%S"` ${1} >> $FILE_LOG
}
```

I have a script that loads an environment file and make a `ps` of a command.  I assign the output of the command to a variable, and then I would like to write the output in `$FILE_LOG`. I do:

```
list="$(ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd | grep -i crack  | grep -v grep)"
...........
LogWrite $list
```

It always shows me only the first field of `ps` (for instance 234324).

Comment: Your LogWrite command only output its first argument.  Either change `${1}` to `"$@"`, or pass everything in the first arg by using quotes: `LogWrite "$list"`

Answer (score 0):

LogWrite is only printing its first argument.  One possible fix:

```
LogWrite() {
    printf "%s: " "$(date '+%Y%m%d %H%M%S')"
    echo "${@}"
} >> $FILE_LOG
```

Another possibility is to place the list into the first argument, which is accomplished simply by properly quoting the argument when LogWrite is called:

```
LogWrite "$list"
```